# How to Add CRUD Operations to a Second Entity in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF program, I use EF and MVVM. I have two entities : Student and Grade. Each student can have multiple grades.  I have one window and one ViewModel(Student). I can add/update/delete student info using the program. When I add grades from database, I can see grades on the screen. I don't know how to modify my program to enable user enter,modify,delete grades on that screen. Can you give me some tips or advices about that? I'm open to new architecture suggestions. Should I add another user control or something like that? Here is my program currently looks like. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Let your grid include an edit column that Populate the textfield when clicked

Comment: You should add another view which will update the grades just like your this view which upgrades the student table,

Comment: Hope this link helps. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28209.wpf-entity-framework-mvvm-walk-through-1.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu should start by modeling the viewmodels in a nice way (**forget everything about database for now**, this has nothing to do with viewmodels & views):

```
public sealed class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel> Students {get; set;}
}

public sealed class StudentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<GradeViewModel> Grades {get; set;}

    public StudentViewModel(){
        Grades = new ObservableCollection<GradeViewModel>();
    }
}

public sealed class GradeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Once you've modelled everything nicely, you'll eventually have list of students somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should add another view for upgrading grades. I am assuming that your are familiar with how to switch views and viewmodels.

In your second view you should add a ComboBox/ListBox. Populate this with from students table.

In your xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding Students} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedStudent} />
```

In your view model.

```
public ObservableCollection Students
{
    get { return DatabaseContext.Students.ToList(); }
}
```

And when you select item in combobox, get grades for the selected student

```
private Student _selectedStudent;
public Student SelectedStudent
{
    get { return _selectedStudent; }
    set
    {
        _selectedStudent = value;
        GetGradesList();
    }
}

private void GetGradesList()
{
    var grades = DatabaseContext.Grades.Where(g => g.Student = SelectedStudent);
    // populate this to grid view like you have done in your current view.
    // And for selected row in the grid you will get values in your textboxes, update those values,
    // and then upgrade that to the database.
}

public void UpgradeGrade()
{
    var grade = DatabaseContext.Grades.FirstOrDefault(g => g == SelectedGrade);
    grade.Value = UpdatedValue;
    DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point I don't know is, how I will pass student's info(id) to the second view that I will make.

Comment: @jason: Not entirely sure what you mean but, first you need to create `StudentViewModel`, and that viewmodel holds list of another viewmodel: `ObservableCollection<GradeViewModel>`. You just bind through students.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Thank you. So, will I need to make another view(window) for grades? If yes, how I will pass the info of selected student? I need to change the grades of the selected student. Thanks.

Comment: I'm really confused in this.. Should I create a new window? If yes, how should I pass data from Students view/window to Grades view/window?

Comment: @jason I am confused too. What do you mean should you create a  new window? Do you want to do so? Either way will work.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Could you tell me how I should do this by creating a new window? Thank you.